# Ubuntu - Consume web service from command prompt

Tags: web-services, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I have built an Ubuntu 12.04 instance on Amazon EC2 and connected to it via putty. I'm trying to call a web service and verify the response.

I'm using following command

```
 curl -d @req.xml -H  "content-type: application/soap+xml" "https://example.com/webservice?wsdl"
```

Here req.xml contains actual XML request. Command runs fine but I'm seeing blank output instead of the actual response. Is there an issue with my syntax?

Comment: Does the call you're making actually return a body, or possibly just headers?  try adding `-D -` to make it `curl -D - -d ...` and see what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason passing the XML request in a file did not work. Instead I modified the command with actual XML request in it and it worked.